# Приём платежей на сайте без агрегата

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

Ребята ,кто знает по какому принципу устроена приём платежей на сайте без сторонних агрегатов типо робокасса и тд

Comment: Без агрегаторов - прямые договора с банками\финансовыми организациями.

Comment: Мне интересно реализация проекта ,по программной части , например у банков есть API который позволяет это сделать ?

Comment: 99% - да, 1% - хз. т.к. большинство таких вещей находится под NDA, то достоверно узнать это, без подписания договора, крайне проблематично. Точнее наличие апи в том или ином виде точно есть, вопрос только в его "виде".

Comment: Есть банки с API для этого, но нужно учитывать, что вам придется работать строго с выбранным банком, а если расчетный счет организации находится в другом банке, то будет доп. комиссия. 

Другой вопрос — зачем вам это? 

Ведь можно взять, например, Яндекс (такой же агрегатор), с максимально адекватным API и можно сделать все так, что никто не узнает, что под капотом Яндекс, а комиссия в этом случае вероятно будет меньше + проще будет настроить Apple Pay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы работать без агрегатора платежей, нужно составить договор с банком. Практически любой банк даёт доступ к API, если их всё устроит